# Get error when try to use jasmine and angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, httpbackend

When I try to use **$httpBackend.flush();** I get error ***TypeError: $browser.cookies is not a function.*** I can't find any information about this kind of error and any solutions.

```js
describe("someText", function() {
    var $httpBackend;
    var someManager;
    var authRequestHandler;

    var dataMockup = [];

    beforeEach(function(){
        module('app');

        inject(function($injector){
            $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
            someManager = $injector.get('someManager');

            authRequestHandler = $httpBackend.when('GET', 'someUrl.php')
                .respond(dataMockup);
        });
    });

    it('test first action', function() {
        $httpBackend.expectGET('someUrl.php');
        messageManager.loadData();
        $httpBackend.flush(); // There i got error
    });
});
```

- Angular: 1.3.15
- Jasmine: 2.3.4

Comment: Make sure you have the right version of angular mocks file as well. https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular-mocks.js

Comment: @PSL, thanks. I didn't noticed that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe you are using the angular mocks for version `1.4.x`, and your code is using angular `1.3.15`. Please check that you are using the mocks for the version you are implementing in your application. Also it is always good to provide your jasmine test configuration file.